# Capture text between 2 keys into a file

Tags: text, capture, keystroke, keylogger

i hope this wasnt asked already - its rather specific and i couldnt find anything.
i am trying to make a script that runs and saves every keystroke between 2 specific keys - lets say, "<" and "Enter" - into a .txt file.
(jfyi, it is to save all messages that go into a "<" chatroom in a game)
i cant seem to find a way how to easily do this - i could start the script with "<" and end it with "Enter" with a loop afterwards, but that seems overcomplicated to me - and i wrong with that or is there a better way to go?

TLDR: i want to make a keylogger that only captures text written after "<" is typed.

Comment: What is the programming language that you are using ?

Comment: oh, sorry, powershell